# Formal way to wish good morning

Tags: grammaticality, formality, greetings

I am not a native English speaker, the source of my learning is books, websites and of course movies and music.
In the movie — if I remember the name correctly — The Last Samurai, I heard that they said "I bid you good morning".

Can I use it as a professional way to wish good morning or is it informal? Or did I just hear it wrong?

Comment: Top o' th' mornin' to ye!

Comment: I grew up in Texas, so it's *Mornin'.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with trex279 that "I bid you good morning" sounds very old fashioned and is overly formal in most cases. If you want something more formal than "Good morning", you could try adding the person's name ("Good morning, Mr/Mrs [name]").

Answer (score 9):

I believe the most widely accepted formal way to bid good morning is just to say "Good Morning"."I bid you good morning" is a bit too verbose, and archaic.

Comment: Yes. It should be "I bid *thee* good morning" for the proper effect.

Comment: It will also make people think you are from some religion that shuns electricity and other modern technology.

Answer (score 2):

Not an native English speaking person, I have lived in the southern US and in Canada and therefore would propose "good morning, sir" and "good morning, ma'am". This works especially well by the way if you forgot a persons name, is very polite and uplifting. Don't try it in New York though, unless you want to provoke an outbreak of amusement. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it either professional or informal. It's archaic, and I'd use it only humourously.